# How to remove last 2 digits from uint?

Tags: solidity

E.g: If I have a uint value of `2000`, how do I make it so that I can get the value of `20`? (Removing the `00` at the end).

Test cases:

```
1234 -> 12
1000 -> 10
500  -> 5
7610 -> 76
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since division of a uint always results in truncation, you can just divide by 100:

```
1234/100 -> 12
1000/100 -> 10
500/100  -> 5
7610/100 -> 76
```

Comment: Just like to add that I can't directly write something like `uint x = 1234 / 100;`. The number 1234 should be in a variable

Comment: @pizzae You can use a cast to force the division `uint x = uint(1234)/100;`